# ng2 Bootstrap Carousel: unable to set active slide value. It always takes slide 1

Tags: angular, carousel, ng2-bootstrap

I am using http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/carousel for my project.

I am able to implement it but slide 1 is always active. I am not sure how to remove the active class from slide1.

The only problem is that I am not able to set the active slide value to a particular value. 
WhenI set the [active] input, I get the slide is set the value for as well as the first slide. 
I am not able to remove the active class for slide 1.

```
<carousel *ngIf="planList" (activeSlideChange)="onSlideChange($event)" [interval]="false">
  <slide *ngFor="let plan of planList" [active]="plan.active">  
      <oe-plan-details [planDetailsSummary]="plan"></oe-plan-details>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

In this case, I have set plan.active for plan-3 as true. I see both plan-1 and plan-3. That is, 2 carousels

Comment: Can you please provide code sample ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 2 way data binding to set active index

```
<carousel [(activeSlide)]="activeIndex">
      <slide *ngFor="let i of items">
        <img [src]="i.image" class="img-responsive" alt="some image">
      </slide>
</carousel>
```

Comment: so can I set it as <carousel [(activeSlide)]=3>
      <slide *ngFor="let i of items">
        <img [src]="i.image" class="img-responsive" alt="some image">
      </slide>
</carousel>

Comment: I dont understand how to set activeSlide value if I want my slide to start from slide 3

Comment: just make sure that variable `activeIndex ` has value `3`

Comment: I tried that: I get this error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '3'. Current value: '0'.

Comment: use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` or make sure that you are initializing `activeIndex` variable in `AfterViewChecked` callback

Comment: I tried setting it in AfterViewChecked and I get the exact same error mentioned above. Any other suggestions?

Comment: try to wrap it in some delay